# How to view Date/Time in the adb.exe output when running in the console?

Tags: android

I'm trying to view LogCat via the command line. I run the following:

```
"C:\path\to\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat
```

and it's displaying the activity that is currently happening. A line by line example of what I'm seeing is

```
E/StrictMode(  654):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/StrictMode(  654):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/ActivityManager(  276): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@410b51f8
D/dalvikvm(  276): GC_CONCURRENT freed 899K, 15% free 7052K/8276K, paused 9ms+26ms, total 248ms
```

What switch to I need to provide to include the date/time in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `adb logcat -v time`

This works for me

Comment: I have to wait 10 mins to select your answer as correct. Have an upvote in the meantime!

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy coding! :)